# is android calendar API the same as google calendar API for android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I want to create an Android app

that creates an event in Google's calendar and attaches a photo to it.

I have googled a bit and couldn't understand if android calendar API the is same as google calendar API

for android?

meaning are the following effecting Google's calendar of the user as well?

if not, can you please help me find out a tutorial how to add an event to google's calendar from an

android app? do I need to download some jar?

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCalendar/article.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Calendar API (v3) is different than so called Android Calendar API.

First approach:
Google Calendar API: You use it when you are making mostly web apps. It also has a Java client that you can use in your application for making Android application that interacts with Google Calendar or other Google services. When using this library user will still have to authenticate and you have to handle it in your app.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Second approach:
Google added Calendar Provider in Android 4.0. You can use it if you are going to support Android 4.0+ only. Your application will not have to handle user authentications. It uses current Calendar of current logged in user on the device.

There are two ways of adding an event using this API.
1) Use Intent for setting parameters and send it to Google Calendar. It will open Google Calendar app and show user option to add the event.

2) If you want to handle everything within your app then use Calendar Provider. It is just like Contact Provider. (Available in Android 4.0+)